# Unity as a Library. can use multiple unityLibrary?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

in unity as a library manual
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/uaal-example/blob/master/docs/android.md

can i use multiple unityLibrary?

ex)

Android Project Root folder

[app]

[unityLibrary1]

[unityLibrary2]

like this

Comment: you might have better luck asking this question directly on the UAAL github repo as a Github Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In their website [Using Unity as a Library in other applications](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/UnityasaLibrary.html), they have mentioned at the end in the Limitations that :

*You can’t load more than one instance of the Unity runtime, or integrate more than one Unity runtime*

So I am thinking it does not work like that. Hope it was helpful.